# Mod Rewrite -- redirect all content from subdirectory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a scenario where there is a a site with subdirectories and content etc originally in a subdirectory `/main`

The site and all content has been moved back to the root and is working fine 
We need to rewrite so that any http call to `/main/`, `/main/page1`, `/main/page2` etc is redirected back to the `/` directory but the uri `/page1`, `/page2` etc

This is what we have so far

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/main/.*
RewriteRule ^/main/(.*) /$1 [L]
```

Any comments welcome 
Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess context, the url that is matched in the first parameter of RewriteRule doesn't include a leading slash and doesn't include the query string. Having a leading slash will cause the rule to never match. In your case your RewriteCond is unnecessary, as it matches exactly what the RewriteRule would match. Change your rule to the following url and it should work. Please note that this is an internal rewrite (the client won't see this change). If you need a redirect (the client will display the url without main in the address bar), add the `[R]` flag to the rule.

```
RewriteRule ^main/(.*)$ $1 [L]
```

See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Comment: Excellent this really helps. It's been a bit of a struggle to figure out how this works